# Python - Urllib3 and Requests connection error shows timeout or proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3, socket-timeout-exception

I'm trying to use the GET method using python-requests but I get an error with the socket connections. Used the urlopen with urllib too but got the same error.

I've been looking for solutions over the internet but nothing seems to work. I'm not using a proxy connection and I've tried keeping a timeout=5 but it doesn't help. (This is what the other solutions suggested)

The basic command - pip3 install "(any_module_name)" also doesn't work giving me the same errors. I've tried reinstalling pip3 but it didn't help.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get('https://www.google.co.in',timeout=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 555, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 753, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 217, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.timeout))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f807b2bcac8>, 'Connection to 172.16.19.10 timed out. (connect timeout=5)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 273, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.co.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f807b2bcac8>, 'Connection to 172.16.19.10 timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 432, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.co.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f807b2bcac8>, 'Connection to 172.16.19.10 timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))
```

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt is cause by the user, you need to show us the error you encountered

Comment: @johnII That was because it wasn't returning any error if I don't give a timeout. I've edited the question, thanks!

Comment: Send a ping request to `https://www.google.co.in` and see if you get a response. Also, what happens when you don't use `timeout`?

Comment: @user8212173 I'm able to ping to https://www.google.co.in successfully. 
When I don't use timeout, it doesn't show me any error until I use the KeyboardInterrupt.

Comment: @user8212173
So I figured out that I can succesfully ping to " http:// www.google.co.in " but not to " https:// www.google.co.in "
And I'm unable to ping to most of the websites. What can I do?

Comment: ping requests are independent of the http scheme. In fact, DNS resolution happens on the hostname only. Take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/930498/difference-between-pinging-with-and-without-http). You will always get ping results with www.google.com without any scheme defined. Are you able to open https websites? then, perhaps you can try `import requests
res = requests.get('http://www.google.com')` and see if that works.

Comment: I'm able to open https websites. The GET method works with google but not with any other URL. I've tried for multiple websites but none of them seem to be working. 
While pinging, I don't define the schema and it works well. But that doesn't work for the GET method. 
Also, thanks for clearing out the ping doubt.